# jQuery - How to add "or" in the Ajax form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I'm trying to add a feature on ajax form to be able using `Submit Button` and `Ctrl+Enter` capability at the same time.
its two separated form, and **it should be as it is**, but two event must be available for submitting the ajax form.
here is what I've done so far:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form").on('submit keydown',(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
          $('.result').html('Ajax Submit');
        },
      });
    }));
  });
```

```html
<input class="search1">
  <form class="form">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div class="result"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Put the `input` inside the form (where it should be) and it happens without the need for any JS. I'd also suggest removing the `keydown` event handler on the `form`

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: there is two separated form, with different values

Comment: it should be separated as it is @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @Andreas the problem is how to add this two event on submitting the ajax form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that in the comments under the question you state that the `input` will not be placed inside the `form` element (although it ***really*** should be, as it's better for accessibility, and also it will solve the issue for you without the need for JS intervention), you can achieve your goal by attaching a `keyup` event handler to the `input` element and listening for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> chord.

Also note that your AJAX request needs to include at least the `url` and `data` as well.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $form = $('.form');
  let $search = $('.search1').on('keyup', e => {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 13)
      $form.submit();
  });
  
  $form.on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('making ajax request...');
    
    /*
    $.ajax({
      url: '/search',
      data: {
        term: $search.val()
      },  
      success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html('Ajax Submit');
      }
    });
    */
  });
});
```

```html
<input class="search1">
<form class="form">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="result"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, but why FormData is not working on it the error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.`

Comment: the input is area for `ajax search` to look for products and add them by jQuery to `form` and create something like `invoice form`

Comment: It's as the error says, the `FormData()` contrsuctor only accepts one argument, and it *has* to be a reference to a `form` element - note this is not a jQuery object holding a form element.

Comment: its only one, the data for form is the `.form` data, not the `.search`

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question about this, making sure to include *all* the relevant HTML and JS, as there's not enough of your code in the question to diagnose the issue.